# Change button and remove div on click

Tags: jquery

I have a script wich adds dynamically new divs with formfields.

Now i want to remove the "add"-button to a "remove" button and on click at the remove button, the main-div `<div id="dyn_template_telefon_1475731106" class="row>` should be remove.

Maybe somebody can help me and show what i have to do for this?

Here is the code from the javascript

```
//Anfang DynamicFields
$(function () {
$(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function () {

//Fallback fuer Timestamp
var TS = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);

//var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
var templateID = $(this).attr('id').replace('dyn_btn_', 'dyn_template_');
var addareaID = $(this).attr('id').replace('dyn_btn_', 'dyn_addarea_');

$('<div/>', {
    'id' : templateID+'_'+TS,
  'class' : 'row',
  html: $('#'+templateID).clone().html()
}).hide().appendTo('#'+addareaID).slideDown('slow');
});
});
function GetHtml() {
  return $('.dynDiv').clone().html();
}
$('.btn-add').click();
//Ende DynamicFields
```

Thats the HTML-Part

```
<div class="row" id="dyn_template_telefon">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group '.$error['telefon']['class'].'">
        <label class="control-label">'.$lang['mod1'][70].'</label>
        <input id="telefon" name="telefon[]" class="form-control" placeholder="" type="text" value="'.$_POST['telefon'].'">
      </div>          
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">'.$lang['mod1'][85].'</label>
        <select id="kategorie" class="form-control " name="kategorie[]" >
          <option value="">'.$lang['mod1'][87].'</option>'.$options['categories'][2].'</select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" id="dyn_btn_telefon" type="button">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
         </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="dyn_addarea_telefon"></div>
```

Comment: Where do you have your remove button or when and how do youchange your add button to remove button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `delete` button, and onclick event of that button, you have to find the id of the Main parent of that div and remove it.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-delete', function () {
    var num = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id').match(/\d+/);
    $('#dyn_template_telefon_' + num).remove();
});
```

**Updated JS**

```
    //Anfang DynamicFields
    $(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function () {

    //Fallback fuer Timestamp
    var TS = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);

    //var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var templateID = $(this).attr('id').replace('dyn_btn_', 'dyn_template_');
    var addareaID = $(this).attr('id').replace('dyn_btn_', 'dyn_addarea_');

    $('<div/>', {
        'id' : templateID+'_'+TS,
      'class' : 'row',
      html: $('#'+templateID).clone().html()
    }).hide().appendTo('#'+addareaID).slideDown('slow');
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.btn-delete', function () {
    var num = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id').match(/\d+/);
    $('#dyn_template_telefon_' + num).remove();
    });


    });
    function GetHtml() {
      return $('.dynDiv').clone().html();
    }
    $('.btn-add').click();
    //Ende DynamicFields
```

**Updated HTML**

```
    <div class="row" id="dyn_template_telefon">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group '.$error['telefon']['class'].'">
            <label class="control-label">'.$lang['mod1'][70].'</label>
            <input id="telefon" name="telefon[]" class="form-control" placeholder="" type="text" value="'.$_POST['telefon'].'">
          </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">'.$lang['mod1'][85].'</label>
            <select id="kategorie" class="form-control " name="kategorie[]" >
              <option value="">'.$lang['mod1'][87].'</option>'.$options['categories'][2].'</select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" id="dyn_btn_telefon" type="button">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
             </button>
            </span>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button class="btn btn-danger btn-delete" id="dyn_btn_telefon_d" type="button">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
             </button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div id="dyn_addarea_telefon"></div>
```

Working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/khairulhasanmd/w9jhpbLy/1/

Comment: great, how i can hide the first remove button, that only for the added rows a remove button is avivable?

Comment: simple trick : you can add the `add` button upper(i mean before `<div class="row" id="dyn_template_telefon">`) so that it would not be copied.

Comment: nice, but that wont work for me - have you another idear how i can display the add button for the first element and hide them for all other elements and show the remove button? Maybe we can change the content of the ".clone" content?